# Opera <table> wrap bug

Tags: html, css, opera, nowrap

I have following html/css:

```
<html>
<body>
<style type='text/css'>
.result_table table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.result_table table td {
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:4px;
  max-height:24px;
  height:24px;
}
</style>
<div class="result_table">
 <table border=1><thead><tr><td>Title</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when "Lorem impsum" has big length (more than 9000 symbols), Opera browser begins to wrap text, even though there is no break symbols and TD has nowrap and overflow directives.

[image]

other famous browser do all good:

[image]

Comment: You forgot to mention which version of Opera.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/ATEDV/ looks fine in Opera 11.01

Comment: Works in Opera 10.51 on WinXP.

Comment: in his question says "more than 9000 symbols". So in Opera 11.01 doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, Opera 10.62. could you please check, i've posted my snipped at http://pastehtml.com/view/1dn8u32.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible `overflow-y:hidden` doesn't work with `display:table-cell` in Opera. O possible solution is to add `display:block` for `.result_table table td`.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qXjV8/

Another solution could be to wrap the text within the `td` with a div and change the selector to `.result_table table td div`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qXjV8/1/

In both cases I advice you to use a reset css like this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Also you will notice that in both cases the second line in Opera is partially visible. To solve this you can use `line-height` property.

Comment: btw, i've found "netsted div" solution myself, but would not like to use it because of large amount of genereated data. it would increase content length

Comment: @heximal yes, I don't think there is reason to use it. The `div` works because its default `display` value is `block`